# QGIS 2.8.2 Wien - Editing problem

Tags: editing, qgis-2.8

I am using QGIS 2.8.2 with Windows 7. After loading the files, I cannot edit them. 
Even when I select one entity, editing buttons are still in grey and cannot be used.

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: what file format are you trying to edit? is the file read-only?

Comment: Have you enabled edit mode?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, just loading the files doesn't allow you to edit them. They are "read only" files. The solution is to save them as a shapefile in order to edit them.

It happens for example when you import GPS tracks in .kml or .gpx.

The actions to do are:
Right click on the layer and select "save as..."

[image]

The next window appears:

[image]

Choose the correct CRS and the folder where you want your shapefile to be saved.
Make sure you mark the dialog "Add saved file to map". A new layer is created with the same items and its attributes, but now you can edit them.

Note: after saving as a shapefile, you can erase the original non-editable file.

Comment: In addition you should check Project Properties->Identify layers.